# How to execute two methods async in RxJava?

Tags: android, asynchronous, system.reactive, execute

How to execute two methods async?
I have two methods call from menu click, and I need second method execute after first.
But I can't understand why result.get() in makeMark() waits Thread.sleep(10000) and getResult  ?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    makeMark(id); 
    try {
       Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
    }
    getResult() //must execute after makeMark() 
    return true
}


public static void makeMark(id){
     databaseCall(id)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(result -> {
            result.get() //why this execute after thread sleep?
)
```

Comment: makeMark is working on IO thread and getting result on Main Thread.
 Thread.sleep(10000); is on Main thread. So you main thread is in sleep mode for 10 sec. Once Main Thread resume  then only result.get() will get execute.